# Personalise Externally Hosted Images URLs in an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html

I hope you can help.

I'm currently working on personalising content for emails, and I reference DE fields to personalise content.

One of the fields that I created is a URL field of different images that I'd like to be personalised to specific users. The images are externally hosted.

When I test send the image errors and doesn't load.

Does anyone have a solution for this one?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of your code -- the part that's not working.

Comment: <tr>
              <td align="center"><a src="%%URL%%"><img data-assetid="25752" src="%%CourseImagePath%%" width="600" height="" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;"></a>
              </td>

Comment: Hi Adam, here is the code. %%URL%% is the field that links to the specific course page advertised, and %%CourseImagePath%% is a field of externally hosted images. Both are pulled from a DE.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily address this by using AMPscript.

```
%%[

set @linkURL = AttributeValue("link")
set @img = AttributeValue("img")

]%%
<br>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@linkURL)=%%"><img data-assetid="25752" src="%%=v(@img)=%%" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;" width="600" height=""></a>
```

[For more information](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/)